# Another Android URI Not Matching

Tags: android, pattern-matching, uri

I've got the following URI setup:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "content://com.danny.servercontentprovider";
// Query URI
private static final int SERVER = 100;
private static final int SERVER_ID = 101;
// Create URI matcher
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
        UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "server", SERVER);
    sURIMatcher
            .addURI(AUTHORITY, "server/#", SERVER_ID);
}
```

but when I call the content provider both uri do not match:

```
int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
switch (uriType) {
case SERVER_ID:
    Log.d(TAG, "A server URI");
    break;
case SERVER:
    // no filter
    Log.d(TAG, "All server URI");
    break;
default:
    Log.i(TAG, "Unknown URI on query: " + uri);
    // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI");
}
```

log message:

```
I/ServerContentProvider(442): Unknown URI on query: content://com.danny.servercontentprovider/server/1
```

When I try the non-numeric uri I get the same error message (without the "/1" in the log message).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change value of `AUTHORITY` to:

```java
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.danny.servercontentprovider";
```